# Kotlin, Bluetooth - intent.getParcelableExtra(Bluetooth.EXTRA_DEVICE) returns Null and crashes

Tags: bluetooth, null, crash, kotlin

```
    var pairedDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
    deviceAdapter = DeviceAdapter(this,pairedDevice)
    bluetooth_listView.adapter = deviceAdapter
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    bluetooth_listView.layoutManager = layoutManager

     mBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    val device = intent?.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    pairedDevice.add(device)
            }
        }
```

pairedDevice.add(device) is the line that seems to crash my program, because device is null.
I have tried checking that it's not null before and it still doesn't fix it.
I have also tried using

```
BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Which also seems to give me null.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I got it too work, by using a MutableList<BluetoothDevice?>

I think the problem was in my recyclerView I was referencing potential Null Values from the BluetoothDevice such as name.

Comment: so, do you know what cause `intent?.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)` hive null value?